# Ruby on rails with acts_as_taggable and RABL overwrites child nodes

Tags: json, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, rabl

I am making a file server on which you upload your files and give attributes. The client side is working on `backbone.js` so i need to send json strings back and forth

The user is able to give tags and colors to the **Document** model, both derived from the `acts_as_taggable` gem.

Now the problem is when i try to make a json from a **Document** collection the different tags collide.

The **RABL** code is as follows:

```
collection @documents
    attributes :id

    child :tags, object_root: false do
        attributes :id, :name
    end

    child :colors, object_root: false do
        attributes :id, :name
    end
```

The result is:

```
[{"id":917, "tags":["color1", "color2"]}, {"id":918, "tags":["color2", "color3"]}]
```

So it seems as if the **colors** overwrite the **tags** node without changing the nodes name.

If i turn it around the **tags** node will contain the tags but no **colors** node will be present.

Comment: Bypassed it by doing this: 
`node :tags do |document|
  document.tags.map{ |tag| {id: tag.id, name: tag.name} }
end` but this cannot be the only solution